# Interagir com serviço do Windows para enviar e receber dados?

Tags: c#, services

Eu criei um serviço no Windows está instalado em localhost e agora tem que interagir com este serviço.

Dentro do meu aplicativo web eu vou dar um comando de consulta que será enviada para este serviço e este serviço vai fazer esta consulta em um outro IP e retornar o resultado para o aplicativo.

Dentro do método OnStart eu criei , um StreamWriter que preenche um txt, para me certificar de que o serviço está funcionando.

Como faço para enviar pedidos para este serviço e receber suas respostas?

Esse é o código do Serviço:

```
namespace ServWin
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        StreamWriter arquivoLog;
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

            arquivoLog = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\JoãoKleber\Desktop\teste.txt", true);
            arquivoLog.WriteLine("Teste de inclusão de Texto, na inicialização do Serviços " + DateTime.Now);

            string ordem;
            string host;
            int port;
            host = "192.168.0.103";
            port = 5000;
            ordem = "outputs";


            IPAddress[] IPs = Dns.GetHostAddresses(host);
            Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            s.Connect(IPs[0], port);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[60];
            s.Receive(buffer);

            byte[] envDados = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ordem + "\n");
            s.Send(envDados);

            byte[] ret = new byte[29];
            s.Receive(ret);

            var tex = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ret, 4, 4).Replace("211", "");

            var vl = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(tex, 16), 2);
            vl = vl.PadLeft(8, '0');
            vl.ToCharArray();
            if (Convert.ToString(vl[7]) == "1") { arquivoLog.WriteLine("Relé 1 Acesso"); } else { arquivoLog.WriteLine("Relé 1 Apagado"); }
            if (Convert.ToString(vl[6]) == "1") { arquivoLog.WriteLine("Relé 2 Acesso"); } else { arquivoLog.WriteLine("Relé 2 Apagado"); }
            if (Convert.ToString(vl[5]) == "1") { arquivoLog.WriteLine("Relé 3 Acesso"); } else { arquivoLog.WriteLine("Relé 3 Apagado"); }
            if (Convert.ToString(vl[4]) == "1") { arquivoLog.WriteLine("Relé 4 Acesso"); } else { arquivoLog.WriteLine("Relé 4 Apagado"); }
            if (Convert.ToString(vl[3]) == "1") { arquivoLog.WriteLine("Relé 5 Acesso"); } else { arquivoLog.WriteLine("Relé 5 Apagado"); }
            if (Convert.ToString(vl[2]) == "1") { arquivoLog.WriteLine("Relé 6 Acesso"); } else { arquivoLog.WriteLine("Relé 6 Apagado"); }
            if (Convert.ToString(vl[1]) == "1") { arquivoLog.WriteLine("Relé 7 Acesso"); } else { arquivoLog.WriteLine("Relé 7 Apagado"); }
            if (Convert.ToString(vl[0]) == "1") { arquivoLog.WriteLine("Relé 8 Acesso"); } else { arquivoLog.WriteLine("Relé 8 Apagado"); }

            arquivoLog.Flush();

        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            arquivoLog.WriteLine("Teste de Inclusão na finalização do Serviço " + DateTime.Now);
            arquivoLog.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: O seu serviço está abrido a porta e escutando? Aconselho usar o IP 127.0.0.1, este sim é localhost.

Comment: Esse é o metodo OnStart do serviço, quando ele é iniciado ele faz algumas anotações em arquivo texto, preciso saber como a partir da aplicação web e possa chamar esse método ou qualquer outro que seja criado dentro do serviço, entende?

Comment: Inicie melhorando seu código. Introduza verificações de erros e tratamento de exceções. Gravando todos os erros em arquivo, pois se trata de um serviço sem interface.

Comment: Eu até pretendo fazer isso, quando conseguir fazer as chamadas a partir da aplicação, no momento não ajuda muito ter um serviço escrito perfeitamente se eu não consigo, ainda, me comunicar com ele.

Comment: @Isalamon Se você tiver alguma sugestão de material ou link de outra pergunta que me ajude a fazer essa comunicação, agradeço desde já...

Comment: sem saber que erro está ocorrendo não há como lhe ajudar. Na Internet você encontra vários exemplos cliente/server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algum tempo atrás eu criei um serviço do windows, este serviço abria um socket para trocar informações com uma aplicação cliente.

Alguns links que pode te ajudar a respeito do modelo servidor e cliente:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @A.Carvalho  Muito obrigado por realmente contribuir par que eu encontre a resposta da minha questão... Esses links são exemplos práticos do que eu com certeza vou utilizar...

Comment: Podes trazer para aqui mais informação que se encontra nesses links? Caso os links deixem de funcionar a tua resposta fica inutil...